# How to Bring tap link status UP

Tags: linux, openwrt

I am trying to create Tap interface in OpenWRT , I created  the Interface using following command:

> ip tuntap add tap_hq mode tap.
> and it shows up when I ran  > ifconfig :

tap_hq    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5A:1B:4D:CE:3B:85
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
but the link status is down , when I ran the command > ip link :
tap_hq: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br-lan state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 5a:1b:4d:ce:3b:85 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

I tried to bring it up using the following command :

> ip link set tap_hq up
> but still it shows status down.
> Can any one help me.